# Copy an image bit by bit C++

Tags: c++, binary, jpeg, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I recently found some documentation on file open modes in C++ and, using `ios_base::binary`, tried to open an image (.JPG), read the bits one by one, and write them in a separate file (`ofstream`) with a .JPG extension. The problem is that I get an error when trying to open the newly created image: `Error interpreting JPEG file`. Any help ?

> code:

```
int main()
{
    char a;
    std::ifstream fin {"image.jpg", std::ios_base::binary};
    std::ofstream fout {"uzicopied.jpg", std::ios_base::binary};
    while (true)
    {
        if (!(fin >> a) || !fin) break;
        fout << a;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fin >> a` skips whitespace, even if the file is opened in binary mode. Use `get` instead. You can also simplify your while loop.

```
char a;
while (fin.get(a))
    fout.put(a);   // fout << a; would also work
```

Comment: oops. It works now, dunno why I didn't think about that. Thanks!